# Handle class event with regular procedure (Delphi)

Tags: delphi, events, delphi-xe, pascal

I am programmatically creating a database connection object inside a simple procedure (not a method in a class).

```
mydb:= TUniConnection.Create(nil);
mydb.Database:= knowledge_db_name;
mydb.LoginPrompt:= False;
mydb.Username:= aaa;
mydb.Password:= bbb;
```

now I need to handle errors and disconnections with other procedures. When I try to do:

```
mydb.OnError:= OnConnectionError;
mydb.OnConnectionLost:= OnConnectionLost;
```

The compiler tells me

```
[DCC Error] test.pas(373): E2009 Incompatible types: 'method pointer and regular procedure'
```

How can I work around this?
Here are the definitions of the event procedures:

```
procedure OnConnectionError(Sender: TObject; E: EDAError; var Fail: Boolean);
procedure OnConnectionLost(Sender: TObject; Component: TComponent; ConnLostCause: TConnLostCause; var RetryMode: TRetryMode);
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you don't have a suitable class to put the event handlers in you can define a dummy class and make the event handlers `class procedure`s. Then you don't have to create an instance of the class but can assign `mydb.OnError:= TMyDummyEventHandlerClass.OnConnectionError;`.

Here is an example - I use different events because I don't have `TUniConnection` but want to be sure everything compiles. :-)

```
type
  // Dummy class to hold event handlers:
  TXMLEventHandlers = class
    // Event handlers:
    class procedure OnBeforeOpen(Sender: TObject);
    class procedure OnAfterOpen(Sender: TObject);
  end;

class procedure TXMLEventHandlers.OnBeforeOpen(Sender: TObject);
begin
  MessageBox(0, PChar(ClassName + '.OnBeforeOpen'), nil, 0)
end;

class procedure TXMLEventHandlers.OnAfterOpen(Sender: TObject);
begin
  MessageBox(0, PChar(ClassName + '.OnAfterOpen'), nil, 0)
end;

procedure Test;
var
  xml: TXMLDocument;
begin
  xml := TXMLDocument.Create(nil);
  try
    // Note: No instance of `TXMLEventHandlers` must be created:
    xml.AfterOpen := TXMLEventHandlers.OnAfterOpen;
    xml.BeforeOpen := TXMLEventHandlers.OnBeforeOpen;

    xml.Active := True; // Calls the two event handlers
  finally
    xml.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Hmmm... this does mean that the "Self" passed to the class procedures is not a class type, it is an instance of a class. I am a little flabbergasted that this assigns without any error.

Comment: @Rudy, AFAIU an event variable is more or less a `TMethod`. `Data` is any pointer and `Code` points to a routine which takes something pointer-like (e.g. a class instance or "meta" variable) as its first argument. From an assembler point of view its all the same.

Comment: The event handler syntax is just syntactic sugar + some type checking added to the concept.

Comment: Yes, but exactly the "syntactic" part and the "type checking" make me wonder why it compiles.

Comment: From an assembler point of view it is all the same. But *in Delphi*, you can't assign a wrong type event handler to an event, so how come you can assign a **class** method to it?

Comment: I guess somebody implemented it in the compiler because it was easy and conceptually sound: If you don't mess around yourself (e.g. with `TMethod` casts) everything fits together guaranteed: either instance variable + regular method or class type ("meta") variable + class method.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117107/discussion-between-uli-gerhardt-and-rudy-velthuis).

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to instantiate an instance of a class on the heap, you could use record methods. I sometimes do that to avoid using the heap, but that approach could be convenient for your needs.

```
type
  TMyEventHandler = record
    procedure OnConnectionError(Sender: TObject; E: EDAError; var Fail: Boolean);
    procedure OnConnectionLost(Sender: TObject; Component: TComponent; ConnLostCause: TConnLostCause; var RetryMode: TRetryMode);
  end;

procedure TMyEventHandler.OnConnectionError(Sender: TObject; E: EDAError; var Fail: Boolean);
begin
  ....
end;

procedure TMyEventHandler.OnConnectionLost(Sender: TObject; Component: TComponent; ConnLostCause: TConnLostCause; var RetryMode: TRetryMode);
begin
  ....
end;

var
  EventHandler: TEventHandler;//global variable

......

mydb.OnError := EventHandler.OnConnectionError;
mydb.OnConnectionLost := EventHandler.OnConnectionLost;
```

Comment: I think Uli's answer is better than this. If I were you I would accept Uli's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your two event procedures need to be methods of a class, instead of local/global procedures. For example:

```
procedure TForm1.OnConnectionError(Sender: TObject; E: EDAError; var Fail: Boolean);
```

Comment: I know that, but the question is if I can do it without using a class (some kind of a cast maybe...).

Comment: If you don't have a class "ready" to put the event handlers in you can define a dummy class and make the event handlers `class procedure`s. Then you don't have to create an instance of the class but can assign `mydb.OnError:= TMyDummyEventHandlerClass.OnConnectionError; `.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Can you provide an example of the global instance of the record?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan You have to try really hard to get the code wrong with a class procedure. The Self parameter for a class procedure is a class reference, not an instance, so you don't even get to accidentally access any class members you may have mistakenly added. A `nil` Self is much easier to accidentally get wrong.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan You indeed wouldn't have an instance, but the compiler wouldn't think you have an instance either (unlike with a nil cast). Try to access an instance member and get a compiler error.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan No, it works. A class procedure does have a hidden `Self` parameter, but it's a class reference (think `TClass`).

Comment: @DavidHeffernan It works. I made sure of that before commenting. :)

Comment: @David, hold on - I'll make my comment a compileable answer. :-)

Comment: Oh, I'm talking a load of rubbish. I've learnt something today! Again! I always assumed that `of object` required instance information. But now I can see that it doesn't and thinking about it I can completely understand why it works fine. Thanks for educating me and sorry for writing such tripe. And a class method is actually a cleaner way to do this than my record approach.

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood. If it weren't for all the comments, I'd have deleted my answer.

Answer (score 0):

While using a `class` method is a clean solution, it is *possible* to use a regular non-class procedure as an event handler, you just can't assign it *directly*, but you can assign it *indirectly* using the [`TMethod`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.TMethod) record.  You will just have to add an explicit `Self` parameter to the procedure.

For example:

```pascal
procedure OnConnectionError(Self: Pointer; Sender: TObject; E: EDAError; var Fail: Boolean);
begin
  ...
end;

procedure OnConnectionLost(Self: Pointer; Sender: TObject; Component: TComponent; ConnLostCause: TConnLostCause; var RetryMode: TRetryMode);
begin
  ...
end;

var
  M: TMethod;
begin
  M.Data := ... whatever you want ...;
  M.Code := @OnConnectionError;
  mydb.OnError := TDAConnectionErrorEvent(M);

  M.Data := ... whatever you want ...;
  M.Code := @OnConnectionLost;
  mydb.OnConnectionLost := TConnectionLostEvent(M);
end;
```

Alternatively:

```pascal
procedure OnConnectionError(Self: Pointer; Sender: TObject; E: EDAError; var Fail: Boolean);
begin
  ...
end;

procedure OnConnectionLost(Self: Pointer; Sender: TObject; Component: TComponent; ConnLostCause: TConnLostCause; var RetryMode: TRetryMode);
begin
  ...
end;

var
  ErrorHandler: TDAConnectionErrorEvent;
  LostHandler: TConnectionLostEvent;
begin
  TMethod(ErrorHandler).Data := ... whatever you want ...;
  TMethod(ErrorHandler).Code := @OnConnectionError;
  mydb.OnError := ErrorHandler;

  TMethod(LostHandler).Data := ... whatever you want ...;
  TMethod(LostHandler).Code := @OnConnectionLost;
  mydb.OnConnectionLost := LostHandler;
end;
```

The benefit of this approach is that you can set the `Self` parameter to whatever value you want, which is useful for passing user-defined data into an event handler.