# Making Delphi events class methods

Tags: class, delphi, events, methods

Sometimes I have a random thought and this is my latest.  Quite often control events don't reference the form/datamodule that they are attached to, which somewhat meets the definition of a class method.  Apart from the IDE complaining (which is pretty much a showstopper as it is so annoying), is there any technical reason why one would not do this.

For instance:

```
class procedure TForm9.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowMessage('Hello World');
end;
```

I've briefly tried this out and seems to work.

Comment: What would be the point? You couldn't use any variables/controls, so why have it part of a visual container in the first place? You can't access the `Sender`, so you could only attach it to a single button (which would have to exist in the first place to be clicked, so there's no reason for it to be a `class procedure`).

Comment: @KenWhite The sender would still be accessible. I like making methods class methods in that it makes it clear that that method will not change the state of the class (which is nice to know when debugging) and it is a good indication that the method may belong elsewhere, and you can usually shuffle them between classes without too much thought.

Comment: @KenWhite Maybe I am being silly and I am missing something obvious but why can't you access sender? It's passed in as a parameter.

Comment: Of course you can access the `Sender`, it's a normal parameter. You cannot access any members of `TForm9` but like in this example this is not always necessary. The reason is rather because methods consist of the Data and the code pointer and the Data is always the instance pointer and not as in the case of a class procedure the class pointer.

Comment: You're right. I'm probably over-thinking. I find it confusing to make it a `class procedure`, which typically means it can be used without an instance of the class being created, and then assigning that to an event handler of a class that must have an instance created in order for the event to be fired (by clicking the button) in the first place.

Comment: @KenWhite Self is definitely not available (compiles but you get an AV), but the sender parameter is fine as it is being passed in.

Comment: @Alister: Yes, but passed in *from where*? The button must have an instance created (presumably meaning that the form it's sitting on must have as well). A `class method` indicates that an instance *need not exist* for the method to be called. How can you click a button that doesn't exist (or even attach that event handler to it in the first place)?

Comment: This type of thing could be useful where you have a class of "standard events". As Stefan indicated below, you could then do a runtime assignment to these "class event" where it makes sense.

Comment: @Graymatter: But that's not what the code in the question indicates. It shows using a class procedure of the containing form itself as the button event handler, which is my objection in the first place. I have no issue with having non-visual classes implementing class methods; my question was about the prudence of using a class method of a visual container as the event handler of a visual control.

Comment: @KenWhite He's not making it a class method because it doesn't read instance-specific fields (it does). He's making it a class method because it doesn't *write* instance-specific fields. If it's a public facing interface, this could be very confusing, but in his case, it's probably fine.

Comment: @Millie: The "could be very confusing" aspect was *my specific point in the first place*. There's absolutely no benefit to doing it this way that would outweigh the confusion/maintenance issues it creates. What is the point of creating a class method that requires an instance of the form to exist in the first place?

Comment: @KenWhite I agree that as the "question" stands, it doesn't make too much sense to do it that way. That's why I said "type of thing". About the only benefit you would get from it is a memory saving but that can be accomplished in a much better way.

Comment: See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11083336/handle-class-event-with-regular-procedure-delphi) for a use case.

Comment: @Alister `Self` is well defined for a class method. Your AV is because the runtime streaming code that synthesises the method pointer (double pointer, code+data) does not recognise that this is a class method and gives you an instance rather than a class for the data pointer.

Answer (score 8):

A non-static class method has a `Self` pointer. That `Self` is the class. Non-static class methods have a `Self` in order to support the dispatch of virtual class methods.

Because non-static class methods have `Self` it means that they can be assigned to `of object` method types as needed for event handlers. So you can certainly write in Pascal code a runtime assignment:

```
Button1.OnClick := TForm1.SomeClassMethod;
```

However, the IDE does not support class methods as event handlers. I believe there is a good reason for this. When the streaming code encounters the setting it looks like this in the .dfm file:

```
OnClick = SomeClassMethod
```

This can only appear in the .dfm file when you put it in manually. That's what I think you mean when you say the that the IDE complains. You added the above to the .dfm file and whenever you load the form the IDE rejects it as invalid.

Now, supposing you do this anyway. Then the streaming code encounters the above .dfm setting as text. It needs to use RTTI to find `SomeClassMethod`. Which is fine. It then synthesises a method value from a data pointer and a code pointer. It uses the instance as the data pointer. And that means that the method is invalid. You cannot pair instance and class method. But the streaming code knows no better and is built on the assumption that the methods found in .dfm files are instance methods. A reasonable assumption given that the designer only offers instance methods.

The code that implements this can be found in `TReader.FindMethodInstance`:

```
function TReader.FindMethodInstance(Root: TComponent; const MethodName: string): TMethod;
var
  Error: Boolean;
begin
  if Assigned(FOnFindMethodInstance) then
  begin
    Result.Code := Root.MethodAddress(MethodName);
    Result.Data := Root;
    Error := Result.Code = nil;
    FOnFindMethodInstance(Self, MethodName, Result, Error);
  end else
    Error := True;
  if Error then
  begin
    Result.Data := Root;
    Result.Code := FindMethod(Root, MethodName);
  end;
end;
```

The pertinent code is assignment of `Root` to `Result.Data` because `Root` is the instance.

So, when the event fires, your method runs but any attempt to use `Self` fails. Because the streaming code has given you an invalid `Self`, an instance instead of a class.

The streaming code cannot properly hook up a class method. And the designer therefore won't offer class methods to use as event handlers. But from code you can perfectly well assign class methods to event handlers and everything works.

Answer (score 6):

You cannot bind them using the form designer or object inspector but you can directly assign them:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Button1.OnClick := TForm1.Button1Click;
end;

class procedure TForm9.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowMessageFmt('%s says hello %s', [(Sender as TComponent).Name, Self.ClassName]);
end;
```

will show: `Button1 says hello TForm9`

It might not make lot of sense if the control and the event handler are in the same class as this class needs to have an instance in order for the control to trigger the event but in many cases they are different classes/instances that are wired together using events.