# calling delphi procedure as method

Tags: delphi, lazarus, freepascal

Here is my simple code which compiles well, but raise Access Violation. It enters MD procedure and debugger displays some X and Y value, but after exiting procedure AV happens. Hope someone can help.

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Controls, Forms,  ExtCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Panel1: TPanel;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

    {$R *.dfm}

procedure MD(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  form1.caption:= inttostr(x)+ ' '+ inttostr(y);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);

function MakeMethod(data, code: pointer): TMethod;
begin
  result.Data:= data;
  result.Code:= code;
end;

begin
  panel1.OnMouseDown:= TMouseEvent(MakeMethod(nil, @MD));
end;

end.
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you surprised by the AV?  - You passing Nil to MakeMethod.

Comment: Same happens if I put pointer to some array of bytes.

Comment: @MartynA, your comments are completely misleading, `MD` never references `data` pointer, the actual reason of failure is parameter mismatch.

Comment: If you don't want to make `MD` a method of `TForm1` you could try the technique I described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11083336/handle-class-event-with-regular-procedure-delphi/11084676#11084676.

Comment: Actually I'm still missing the motivation for this. The question is unclear and should be rephrased as to what is the goal. Otherwise this here is doomed to never be found again by people who are actually having the same problem but don't use the same wording in their search.

Comment: @Sherlock70 Indeed. `MD` alread *is* tied to `TForm1` because it uses the `Form1` variable, so why not make the connection explicit and save all the hassle.

Comment: @Uli Gerhardt - Yes, I was aware of that solution and it works OK. However solution with class procedures raises compile problems with Lazarus (it is my prime interest) which I didn't understand. However this should be for some other thread.

Comment: @Djole, I added tags to reflect the Lazarus relation.

Comment: @Uli Gerhardt- form1,caption was just first that come to me, but generally of course, there could be something which is not part of Tform. And once more- it was just my wish to understand why problems arise with global procedures.

Comment: @Uli Gerhardt - Sorry I didn't see your Lazarus notation at first glance. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

`MD` signature should include additional hidden parameter; it solves AV issue.

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, ExtCtrls;


type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Panel1: TPanel;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure MD(Instance, Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  form1.caption:= inttostr(x)+ ' '+ inttostr(y);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);

function MakeMethod(data, code: pointer): TMethod;
begin
  result.Data:= data;
  result.Code:= code;
end;

begin
  panel1.OnMouseDown:= TMouseEvent(MakeMethod(nil, @MD));
end;

end.
```

Comment: Care to explain why `OnCreate` isn't good place? I never have any problem with that. VCL/FMX also does that as the step of `Create` sequence.

Comment: @FreeConsulting - my fault, works with `OnCreate` too. Edited.

Comment: Thanks user246408. I tried sometime with assigning onClick event and it works well even without hidden parameter:
panel1.onclick := TNotifyEvent(MakeMethod(nil, @PanClick))  and

Comment: Sorry I hit Enter button accidentally- I wanted to add:
procedure PanClick(sender: tObject);
begin   form1.Caption:= 'some text'; end;
That works and it missled me

Comment: @Djole, it worked because not all `TMouseEvent` parameters can fit into registers, so uses stack. And so causes misaligned stack when you mismatch the signature.

Comment: @FreeConsulting Thanks for in-depth explanation. Sounds reasonable,

Comment: [This technique](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11083336/handle-class-event-with-regular-procedure-delphi/11084676#11084676) is basically the same without the hackery. :-)

Comment: Using a class method is without doubt a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try making MD a member of your form class. Edit your example the following way:
In the class definition:

```
type
TForm1 = class(TForm)
  Panel1: TPanel;
  procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  procedure MD(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
end;
```

Later in your code make sure to enter the owner of the MD method like so:

```
procedure TForm1.MD(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
```

Finally, when assigning this eventhandler to your component, all you have to do is:

```
panel1.OnMouseDown:= MD;
```

I don't know what your intention was, but that is how you take care of eventhandlers at run time.

Comment: I know that, but I intentionally try to use global function, rather then method. It was just the matter of curiosity.

Comment: Perhaps clarify your intention. I simply don't see the need for doing things the way your example suggests. Perhaps try your method with something other than an event handler. Try something simple first, maybe a method without parameters, then work yourself up to methods with parameters.